# JHipster: H2 console not loading correct database?

Tags: h2, jhipster

I generated a web application using `JHipster` and added a few entities via the [`jhipster import-jdl`](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/) command (e.g. `Title`). I added an entity instance of `Title` manually via the GUI and the list now shows that new entry. When I connect to the `H2` database as role `admin` I do not see a table regarding the added entity but obviously it should be there. The `JDBC url` is `jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/myapp` and the folder contains a `myapp.trace.db` and `myapp.mv.db` file. The `myapp.mv.db` file seems to hold the actual database due to its file size.

[image]

What am I missing? The database tells me that there is no such table:
[image]

I didn't change any default settings such as database location. Why does it not display the added tables when the application clearly has them?

Comment: How do you connect to h2 ? Using jhipster menu ?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou: Yes, via the `Administration` -> `Database` link on the default generated website.

Comment: Really strange!

Comment: Regardless, I went with `PostgreSQL` now since it seems to be a more "mature" choice. It works as expected so the fact that I never got `H2` to work correctly doesn't matter to me anymore. I saw `H2` work without any issues in another JHipster-based project (created in 2016) though which makes it pretty strange.